# Pulling multiple strings using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am attempting to pull the names of the restaurants on Eater by scraping it; however it is proving difficult because the first string is the ranking Eater has given it (ex. 1, 2, 3, etc.). As can be seen in the HTML below:

```
<h2>
<span class="c-mapstack__card-index">1</span> 
Merkelbach</h2>
```

My code currently grabs the 1, which is fine, but it's imperative that I grab the name of restaurant as well. So I want to grab "Merkelbach". My code is below, any insight would be great.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Python27\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('http://www.eater.com/maps/best-amsterdam-restaurants')
for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "c-mapstack__card-index"]'):
    print elem.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My code currently grabs the 1, which is fine, but it's imperative that I grab the name of restaurant as well

You should locate `<h2>` element instead of `<span>` as below :-

```
for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//h2[span[@class = "c-mapstack__card-index"]]'):
    print elem.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to access the text within the `h2`, which is the parent of the `span`. You can access the `h2` by selecting the parent from the xpath by appending the xpath with `/..`:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Python27\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('http://www.eater.com/maps/best-amsterdam-restaurants')
for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "c-mapstack__card-index"]/..'):
    print elem.text
```

note this will have both the number and the name, you can split it yourself, or use your previous xpath to get the text of just the span and remove it from the text of the parent